# Samba 4.7 - issue with UNC access via hostname/fqdn

Tags: ubuntu, samba, smb

Running Samba 4.7.6 on U18.04. Everything was working prior to a recent shutdown, in that you could access the shares via `\\hostname\` or `\\hostname.domain.com\`. Now, these fail on Windows clients with error 0x8004005. However, we found that if one fully-qualifies the domain like `\\hostname.domain.com.\` (notice trailing period after the ".com") then it works! (displays shares in Windows Explorer.) We are using ADS security, using winbind, and the machine is domain-joined. Is this some kind of strange Kerberos issue? How might I go about diagnosing/fixing?

Comment: Do you get correct answers on a "failing" Windows client from `ping`? By IP address of the Samba Server, then unqualified name, qualified name, and finally qualified name with the trailing dot. You're in an AD environment, so have you checked the SPN values for the Samba Server's host name?

Comment: Yes, DNS pings (short name, fqdn without & with trailing dot) all work from a host that fails to mount. Will ask my AD admin about the SPN value of the machine object in AD.

Comment: Also as a "silly" check that the Samba Server is using the same time source as the rest of your AD network, and that it's got the same time to within about a minute or so. Ideally +/- just a few seconds, but Kerberos is reasonablly flexible. (It should be synchronised, but just check.)

Comment: As far as the SPN goes - other Samba servers joined to the AD domain have SPN values of `HOST/<hostname>` and `HOST/<fqdn>`, as well as `RestrictedKrbHost/<hostname>` and `RestrictedKrbHost/<fqdn>`; the malfunctioning one just has the `HOST/...` values. Would this be the issue?

Comment: Also time sync is OK (uses our DC's as NTP time sources.)

Comment: I've not come across RestrictedKrbHost before